# Grafana not showing docker metrics on 193 json file

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana, metrics

I configured grafana, prometheus, nodeexport to my project. I am able to see node export full report from grafana. This is showing my vm details properly. I am running the 9 containers in the same vm. I am able to see the metrics using http://vm-ip:9786/metrics showing the docker metrics. I want to show docker metrics also using grafana. I am using json file from https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/193. I am uploaded this json file in to grafana and added a promethues as datasource. But it is not showing any metrics regarding docker system. Am i doing any mistakes here?.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my question. This 193 dasboard is for cadvisor. I am running cadvisor container in my vm, added  target in prometheus, added prometheus as a data source in grafana. Now i am able to see the dashboard.